# How to resume a file transfer using netcat or socat or curl?

Tags: networking, tcp, netcat, file-transfer, socat

I have to transfer a 400Gb database consisting of a single file over the Internet from a server where I have full control to an other computer at the opposite border of the ocean (but which uses a slow connection). The transfer should take a full week and in order to reduce all protocol overhead (even using ftp would had 10Min overhead), I’m using a raw tcp connection.

I already transferred 10% of the file, but I learned there will be a scheduled outage in some hours.

How can I ask netcat or socat or [curl](https://superuser.com/a/925610) to serve the `FILE:database.raw` at the offset it was interrupted? or

Comment: And this is why `rsync` is a disconcertingly good idea

Comment: @roaima even for a single file without having to care about file permissions? Isn’t rsync supposed to be a layer over tcp or udp? Also, no idea if I would be able to resume what’s already transfered that way.

Comment: Its big win is that it's (trivially) restartable

Comment: @roaima the same as http then I suppose. But adding a 500bytes header inside each tcp packet. More seriously, I know how to resume the download, I just don’t know how to do it using a raw tcp socket again.

Comment: Is the 400GB after compression?

Comment: The other question, which isn't really technical, is whether it would be quicker/easier to post a CD

Comment: @roaima I don’t have physical access to the remote server. 400Gb is before compression but the data isn’t compression friendly so this doesn’t worth the time lost at compressing the file.

Comment: What commands did you use to transfer the first 10%? In order to resume the task, it would be nice to know how it was started.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani  `socat ‑u FILE:somedatabase.raw TCP-LISTEN:4443,keepalive,tos=36`. Notice that because there’s no fork, the command stops listening after the first connection. So it’s really plain ᴛᴄᴘ without any kind of protocol above.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I can also use `IP4-LISTEN:` for even faster speed since it’s the only communication happening with that address. The result wouldn’t contain errors per se, but then I’m not sure that the data would be written/received in the same order it was sent.

Comment: it is good to do a few check sum when doing such a bare metal.way of  transfering.   You can produce a series of md5sum out of the file at source , repeat the process at the other end and compare all of them.  ```head -c 2gb largefile |tail -c 1 gb|md5sum```  produce the md5sum of the 2nd gb of the file named largefile.  you want a small script to manage these md5sums.

Comment: @bigdataolddriver there’s no point at doing it since in my case the source file may be already corrupt. The only way to do is to load it which can be only performed on a computer with physical access which is the point of such transfer.

Comment: @roaima but in an other case, my partner don t want to hear about it stating it would take too much time to type an rsync command instead of nectat one. And I didn t found someone else able to share his OpenEthereum database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your command, as stated in the comments is:

```
socat -u FILE:somedatabase.raw TCP-LISTEN:4443,keepalive,tos=36
```

you can, on the sending side, do a `seek` and start serving from there:

```
socat -u gopen:somedatabase.raw,seek=1024 TCP-LISTEN:4443,keepalive,tos=36
```

on the receiving side you also need to seek:

```
socat tcp:example.com:4443 gopen:somedatabase.raw,seek=1024
```

Check the manpage for `socat`, there are other options you might be interested in.

Comment: Thank you. How do I get the seek value ?

Comment: Check the how many bytes you received so far and use that value. An `ls -l` should do it.

Comment: I mean shouldn’t I add 1 or remove 1 to the value or `ls -l` in order to get the seek value ?

Comment: I checked it with the same value I got with `ls`. Be aware that you cannot run that multiple times because it will append. In that case, if you are not sure, you could also check the `ftruncate` flag in `socat`. `seek-end` can be also useful. You've taken the one of the hardest roads, so be prepared for some bumps. If you feel like testing your commands, using a small text file might help you see how all those parameters interact, though you should run something like `md5sum` to verify.

Comment: Last question, am I correct to assume that a transfer using `IP4-LISTEN` of socat will produce an incorrect result in even if it’s the only communication which is happening with the remote server ?

Comment: You cannot guarantee a correct transfer using just IP. It's not just about the server, or the client, it's about everything in between.

Comment: I m having an other case, how to seek, or rather start sending from an offset if the file is generated from stdin?